# Adding custom XSLT libraries for use in the Search Core Results web part

Tags: search, xslt

Out-of-the-box, the Search Core Results web part only supports XSLT 1.0. The last thing I read [from Chris Lovett](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/11/16/chris-lovett-interview.aspx) on the MS XML team is that Microsoft don't have plans for XSLT 2.0. This makes the possibilities limiting at times!

Is there any way to use a custom library such as [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/) within this web part to enhance transforms with regular expressions and other functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously had to inline the custom libraries functions into an xslt file hosted in SharePoint and linked to the xslt property in the webpart (I prefer linking to a file over adding the xslt in directly).

Linking libraries seems to produce a security issue and you are certainly not allowed to reference C# functions in the xslt.

In cases where I have more advanced functions required from any xslt rendering, I have resorted to creating a custom webpart.

Comment: After looking at this for some time, I think a custom web part is the only option. Thanks Nat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is on the browser side, since [XSLT 2.0 is not supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet%5FExplorer) in IE8.

I wish I could provide you with a better answer here but I tried to implement EXSLT within data view web part, and failed! I am not an XSLT guru, but I think the problem was caused with some incompatibilities with the dwp namespace. At the end I gave up :(.

Comment: @Toni: Are you sure the problem is on the browser side? The raw HTML appears to have been already processed?

Comment: I was under the impression it is being processed on the browser side... but I might be wrong... XSLT is not my game... but one cannot avoid it... It would be nice to add EXSLT in SharePoint but I do not know how to proceed... maybe some will have an idea...